# Errors upgrading from Xamarin.Android to .NET MAUI (APT2259 & APT2061 )

Tags: android, xamarin.android, maui

I am doing a migration of a project from Xamarin.Android to .NET MAUI. I used the Visual Studio Upgrade tool. Afterwards, when I rebuild the project, I get these errors:

```
**Error  APT2259 **  'textEnd' is incompatible with attribute iconGravity (attr) flags [start=1, textStart=2]. 
mtrl_calendar_month_navigation.xml    33
```

(Location: C:\AndroidAppCore\res\layout\mtrl_calendar_month_navigation.xml)

```
**Error  APT2061 ** failed linking file resources.
Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets      156
```

(Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.43\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets

What I've tried, I've gone through the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/upgrade-assistant?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vswin
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-multi-project?view=net-maui-8.0

I don't see much documentation on going from Xamarin.Android (aka native) to MAUI. Its mainly from Xamarin Forms to MAUI.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can refer to this issue : [[Bug] Cannot upgrade to XF 5.0.0.1874 Failed linking resource file textend is incompatible with attribute gravity](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13303). It has the same error as yours and the Author said:

> with
>   removing this library and replacing with Xamarin.Google.Material ,
> Fixed below error.
> the Error 'textEnd' is incompatible with attribute iconGravity (attr) flags [start=1, textStart=2] [weak].
> then I had other errors that were solved by cleaning up no longer used Android.Support.Library

And then, you can read the official document about [Xamarin.Android project migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/android-projects?view=net-maui-8.0). It shows the details and steps to migrate the xamrarin.android project to .net 8 project.